# PostgreSQL show milliseconds in time type

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why when I select time type show only hours, minutes and second but not milliseconds like in SQL Server? I try use precision in time type like `time(6)` but it is not work. And what mean this precision in time type if it not for store milliseconds?

```
select now()::time(6)
```

returns

```
10:23:00
```

Comment: Maybe your SQL client simply doesn't display that information. Try `select to_char(now(), 'hh24:mi:ss.us')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and what mean precision?

Comment: When I do `select now()::time(6)` I get `11:15:25.948316` see [dbfiddl](https://dbfiddle.uk/8SLQCL4j)

Answer (score 1):

show only hours, minutes and second:

```
select now() ::time(0);
```

show time info at maximum precision:

```
select now() ::time(6);
```

show time info at Millisecond level.

```
select now() ::time(3);
```